# How to copy a project from codeplex to GitHub

Tags: github, ethics

Since codeplex hub is disappearing, some projects have not been moved by their owners to other places.

What would be the process of moving someone else's project?

Comment: This question was [originally asked on Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/351836/60357) and has an answer there. Do you have a more specific question than that, e.g. about the terms of a particular license or about other aspects of mirroring a project? If so, please [edit] the question. Don't just cross-post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: First of all U.S. It ethical ? But also all other dimensions are important too. I don't want to do something ethical and next end up being sued !

Comment: @amon I'll edit, right now I am in mobile

Comment: Make a fork(if the license permits) and copy it to github... This is done more frequently you can imagine.

Comment: @nwildner : That is the answer to the question I should have asked! How to do it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to check the software License. If it is some of the opensource licenses that will enable you to make a fork, is just a matter of importing code on github. Depending on the license, you can relicense, or you will be forced to change the name of your new forked project(maybe someone owns the "brand" of this software, like Linux is a [trademark of Linus Torvalds](https://lmi.linuxfoundation.org/programs/legal/trademark/attribution)).

Since creating a step-by-step on how to import code on github is off-topic, I suggest you to take a time to read the documentation of the [Github Importer Tool](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-source-code-to-github/). The [about page](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-importer/) gives more details on what source control software is supported. From here, it is just a matter of set the Codeplex url on your new Github repo and execute the import.

This answer can also apply to other repository management tools, if they use the same Version Control Source tools that are supported by github. You can even use [external tools](https://help.github.com/articles/source-code-migration-tools/) to make the source code migration if using github importer is not an option for any reason.